# PHP - Extraer el contenido entre 2 delimitadores da error

Tags: php, preg-match

estaba intentando generar un regex para preg_match pero no entiendo por qué me da error, es simplement epara 4extraer la información entre 2 delimitadores, pongo elejemplo

```
function image_ext($input) 
{
$regex='/^.*/.*;.*$/';
return preg_match($regex, $input);
}

echo image_ext("text/plain;base64");
```

**El resultado es siempre el mismo :**

```
Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '.'
```

Entonces no entiendo que será lo que está mal, a ver si me podéis ayudar con esto, estaba utilizando esta aplicación online que me generor el código para la selección :

https://regex-generator.olafneumann.org

**Resuelto con :**

```
$string = 'text/plain;base64';
if (preg_match('/\/(.*?)\;/', $string, $matches)) {
    $extractedText = $matches[1];
    echo $extractedText;
}
```

**Saludos.**

Comment: A mi no me arroja ningún warning, pero en todo caso no me queda claro lo que intentas hacer, porque `preg_match` no te va a extraer nada

Comment: Yo creo que te equivocas ya lo he corregido y era que estaba mal  este era el correcto /\/(.*?)\;/

Comment: Recuerda que si tienes conflictos con el delimitador, puedo escaparlo como has puesto en tu solución, o bien puedes usar un delimitador diferente, como `#`.

Comment: Probaste [_explode()_](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)?

Comment: @Jean No veo en que parte de mi comentario puedo estar equivocado, pero que bueno lo hayas solucionado